# add JDBC to Dynamic Web Project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jdbc

I am working with JSP and have a problem adding JDBC driver to my current project. I tried to build a path to jdbc library as well as copy and pasting JDBC jar directly into "lib" folder, but nothing works, i keep getting "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" error. Am i doing something wrong? is there other way to add jdbc?

Jar appears as follows in the picture: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you loaded the class correctly?
try this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

just before creating the connection.

Comment: Just a note: any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)